# Get Value from Column in Plugin Table

Tags: customization, table

I am using Time.ly's All-In-One Event Calendar plugin. I am trying to get a value from the wp_ai1ec_event table in the column entitled "end". I want to get this based on the post_id. Since this is a custom table it's post_id is the same as the post table's. I have tried everything I can think of to get this value. Been working on it for days, trying all the results I get from Google searches. Nothing seems to work. I've tried:

> $event_date = get_post_meta($HitID, 'end', true);

and

> $event_date = mysql_query("SELECT end FROM wp_ai1ec_event WHERE
>   post_id = '".$HitID."'");

Among many other things. These seemed to be the closest.

Nothing I have tried works. I simply do not have enough self-taught PHP ability to get this working. Any help would be appreciated.

The goal is to get the value in the table column "end" of the table "wp_ai1ec_event" based on the post_id, in this case $HitID.

Comment: did you try printing your whole meta array to make sure the field you want is actually there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These bigger plugins are often "too cool" to use post_meta/post_custom - thats why you were unable to retrieve the data via the normal plugin way of storing additional info. The dev documentation for ai1ec in bleak, I couldn't find any functions to simplify the task you were after (though they do exist in the source code if browsed long enough).

The table you're after is `wp_ai1ec_events` (plural. not `wp_ai1ec_event`).

Using a tool like phpmyadmin is a great way to build your queries before hand, then make the work in your php code.

I was able to retrieve the `end` date information with the following:

```
add_action('init','myplugin_get_alic_enddate');
function myplugin_get_alic_enddate() {
    global $wpdb;

    $HitID = 537; // wtv
    $query = "SELECT end FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}ai1ec_events` WHERE `post_id` = {$HitID}";
    $event = $wpdb->get_row($query); 

    //echo $event->end;
    //echo date(get_option('date_format'),$event->end);
}
```

This does nothing with events that are all day events or ones with no end date set (obviously).

**UPDATE**

To reflect the code posted by OP in another answer

```
add_filter('relevanssi_hits_filter', 'rlv_remove_expired');

function rlv_remove_expired($hits) {
    global $wpdb;

    $non_expired = array();
    $now = time();

    foreach ($hits[0] as $hit) {

        $HitID = $hit->ID;
        $Result_PostType = get_post_type($HitID);

        if( $Result_PostType == 'ai1ec_event' ){

            echo "<pre>Made it to: if(Result_PostType=='ai1ec_event')</pre>";

            $query = "SELECT end FROM {$wpdb->prefix}ai1ec_events WHERE post_id = {$HitID}";
            $row = $wpdb->get_row($query); 

            if($wpdb->last_error !== '') {
                echo "<pre> MYSQL ERROR:\n";
                $wpdb->print_error();
                echo "</pre>";
            }

            $end_date = $row->end;

            echo "<pre>In Function.\n End Date: ".$end_date."\n HitID: ".$HitID."</pre>";

            if($end_date >= $now)
                $non_expired[] = $hit;

        } else {
            $end_date = 0;
            $non_expired[] = $hit;
        }

        echo "<pre>Hit ID: ".$HitID."\n End Date: ".$end_date."\n Now: ".$now."\n Post Type: ".$Result_PostType."</pre>";
    } // end foreach

    $hits[0] = $non_expired;
    return $hits;
}
```

Comment: This is VERY close I think, but is not working for me.

Comment: IT WORKS!!! You sir, are a programming GOD. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: Question: Is this part necessary?              if($wpdb->last_error !== '') {
                 echo "<pre> MYSQL ERROR:\n";
                 $wpdb->print_error();
                 echo "</pre>";
             }

Comment: I would rather nothing happen than show MYSQL ERROR in the search results.

Comment: not necessary, just helps a ton while developing. The best way would be to wrap it in `if (WP_DEBUG) { ... }` so it only fires when you're in actually debuging.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this. Much further than I have gotten.
Here is my complete filter code. This code is to make it so that only non-expired events show in search. I have put your code, David Sword, in but needed to comment out some of it to get to run. Also, in your code (or how it was marked as code by the stackexchange) you have the " ' " as " ` " which generated an error so I changed them to normal single quote.

```
        add_filter('relevanssi_hits_filter', 'rlv_remove_expired');function rlv_remove_expired($hits) {
$non_expired = array();
$now = time();
foreach ($hits[0] as $hit) {
    $HitID=$hit->ID;
    $Result_PostType=get_post_type($HitID);
    if($Result_PostType=='ai1ec_event'){
        echo "<strong>Made it to: if(Result_PostType=='ai1ec_event')</strong><br>";

        //add_action('init','myplugin_get_alic_enddate');
        //function myplugin_get_alic_enddate() {
            global $wpdb;
            $query = "SELECT end FROM '{$wpdb->prefix}ai1ec_events' WHERE 'post_id' = {$HitID}";
            $end_date = $wpdb->get_row($query); 
            echo "<strong>In Function.<br>End Date: ".$end_date."<br>HitID: ".$HitID."</strong><br>";
        //}
        if($end_date >= $now){
            $non_expired[] = $hit;
        }
    }else{
        $end_date = 0;
        $non_expired[] = $hit;
    }
        echo "<p>Hit ID: ".$HitID."<br>End Date: ".$end_date."<br>Now: ".$now."<br>Post Type: ".$Result_PostType."</p>";
           }
           $hits[0] = $non_expired;
           return $hits;
        }
```

Comment: the `get_row` function returns object, so `$end_date` has return an entire row thats an object - as such it should be `$end_date->end`. You can't replace the back-ticks with single quotes for table and column names - mysql will error. You should declare your global's at the top of the function. I should of included some mysql error handlers. Turning on `WP_DEBUG` in `wp-config.ph`p may also help you. I've updated my reply with your expanded code.